# window.open ask for popup permission from browser on submit event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on a project. I am facing a problem that when user submit their id and password and click on submit i check user in to database and when it matched i am opening a new window by window.open script but it always ask for permission from browser to open popup.
I just want to open new window without popup browser permission

This is my submit button

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In" class="login_button"    style="border:none; background:none; font-size:14px; padding:0px; margin-top:5px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff" />   

<?php
if($user->login == 1){
     $this->loginUser($user);
?>
   <script> 
   var h = screen.height;
   var w = screen.width;
   window.open("<?php echo CreateURL('index.php',"mod=guidelines"); ?>", 'newwin', 'height='+h+'px,width='+w+'px')</script>
   <?php
}
else{
   $error .= "You are not authorized to login. Please contact system administrator.";
} 
?>
```

Comment: well I guess it's a security feature you cant disable

Comment: Use `_blank` instead of `newwin`, so it opens a new tab instead of a new window which does not require special permissions.

Comment: Instead of attempting to disable a browser safeguard, why don't you just call your PHP with AJAX and show the response in a modal window?

Answer (score 0):

**you will have to enable popups because window.open opens a popup.**

> 1) for chrome setting --> privacy --> content-settings check allow
>   popup. 2) for IE tools --> privacy --> turn off popup blocker

Comment: But it's from user perspective. When making any program, taking steps to enable/disable some features on user computer is useless, since you can't do that on all world's computers.

Comment: you'll have to atleast on the system you configure or guide them to. I have this problem in my apps for a long time, I would also like to know if there is another workaround

Comment: I would migrate to another similar site

Comment: I alrady done this but it is not a solution for this.

Comment: new window open without any permission in onclick event but i am not using on click event first i check user acess then i open a window so it is not a click event..

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

```
<?php
if($user->login == 1){
$this->loginUser($user);
?>
<!-- USE TARGET WHAT EVER YOU WANT -->
<a target="_parent" href="<?php echo CreateURL('index.php',"mod=guidelines"); ?>" id="test-ak">&nbsp;</a> 

<script> 
var h = screen.height;
var w = screen.width;
document.getElementById('test-ak').click(); // try something like that if you dont care about the window size
</script>

<?php
}
else{
   $error .= "You are not authorized to login. Please contact system administrator.";
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser will always ask for permission from browser to open popup if open popup request is not generated by user click.

So you have two option to avoid this popup blocker.

1. check user in to database using synchronous ajax call and in same call on ajax success open window popup.
2. After successful check of user from data base show user some type of dialog and ask user to   click on some button and on that button click write your open window function.